# Prevent standard select behavior on the mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, select

Good afternoon, can you please tell me how to disable the standard panel select call on ios?

here I have a custom select and I need to disable the standard select panel, tried

`preventDefault ()` - does not help

tried to disable focus `blur ()` - does not help

P.S. Custom select using Select2
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with `Select2` plugin on iOS devices when it is used within a form. You can try hiding a native `select` element via CSS to get rid of it's action:

```
select {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```